Community Bot configuration - pushes very old questions up
is there a way to configure he community bot? I saw that it edited some unanswered questions which are from 1 year+
I don't think that there is a benefit of having those questions popping up again.
Here are some examples:
Error on WebSocket connection to Infura Ropsten (broken close frame) ~5 years
How to read start trading function ~2 years
Is it possible to verify a node is running remotely? ~3 years

I haven't found between the tools available to mods a way to configure old questions.
